# Regex a portion of string with a specific patten

Tags: regex

I have a bunch of marketing data where Ad name has creative name included in it, in the format below. The creative name would always be in 4th position, how I extract in a faster manner?

```
Market | Brand | Campaign name | Creative | Product
```

I tried as below with some online help,

```
^(?:[^|]*\|){3}\s([^|]*)\s
```

technically I get creative name but this is slow and I see a message Avoid nested quantifiers as they can cause catastrophic backtracking. I am using a tool called funnel.io to pull in the data from platforms.

Comment: How do you know it is slow? Does it hang the app/Web site? Nested quantifiers are only evil if you do not know what you are doing. `^(?:[^|]*\|){3}\s([^|]*)\s` will not cause any serious backtracking issues in the majority cases. `\s([^|]*)\s` is a bit stange, you might use `\s*([^|]*[^|\s])`, and the backtracking involved will be minimal and beneficial.

Comment: Do you have to use a regexp? Most languages have a function for splitting a string using a delimiter. Split the line using ```|``` as the delimiter, and then get the 4th element of the array.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew because in the tool when i try to create a new dimension with this rule, it does not let me and throws the above error

Comment: Are you sure it is treated as an *error*? If so, disable anything that throws the error. It is not.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the tool doesn't have option to disable, it just throws - Regex may run very slow. Avoid nested quantifiers as they can cause catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: What is the point in extracting something that doesn't change? Your regex should be `.*Creative.*` then, don't you agree?

Comment: @vmp creative is a placeholder. It can 'ABCD', 'EDFG', 'ERGES' but this value will always be in second position of the string pattern.

Comment: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4784 is too strict. There must be a way to turn this rule off.

Comment: What about `^.*|([^|]+)|[^|]*$` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting on delimiter would be easier in this case, but to avoid the nested quantifiers validation you can instead use multiple capturing groups like this: `^([^|]+)\s\|\s([^|]+)\s\|\s([^|]+)\s\|\s([^|]+)\s\|\s([^|]+)$`

This also describes your naming convention using `\s\|\s` delimiters between 5 `([^|]+)` capturing groups and the Funnel plattform supports picking which capture group to extract. You can re-use the same regex for the other fields.

- Group 1 - Market
- Group 2 - Brand
- Group 3 - Campaign name
- Group 4 - Creative
- Group 5 - Product